# Custom wrapper for log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I want to build a wrapper around log4j2 to do the below:
1) There are around 6 mandatory fields like event_name, action, desc etc 
2) Some fields, i want to make them use only certain values, like enum
3) log should be created in key value pairs for Splunk.

Below is my approach:
1) Created a class called CustomLogger accepeting the mandatory fields, logger and variable fields as key value
2) Users can call methods like below:

```
CustomLogger.info(logger, transactionId, app_name, event_name,
                "inside the loop", "inside the loop of the sample app",
                CustomLogger.Result.success, "looped in", "loop_count",
                String.valueOf(i));
```

Method definition:

```
public static String log(LogLevel logLevel, Logger logger,
        String transactionId, String app_name, String event_name,
        String action, String desc, Result result, String reason,
        String... addtnlFields)
```

Issues with the approach:
1) Not extending the log4j, not sure if this is the right way
2) need to pass the logger from every class. If that can be avoided
3) method and line number is lost since it is getting called from a different method

This will be widely used across my internal applications, so want to do it right. Is this approach ok or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code generator attached to this Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-519

Perhaps you can use that as a base class? Gives you a slightly nicer API.
(I still need to update this to reflect some API changes in log4j-2.0-rc2...)

---

UPDATE

A different approach is to have a custom implementation of the Message interface defined in the log4j2 api module. Your custom message would have a constructor with all fields you define as required, and the toString method (and perhaps some other methods too) would format these fields as you require into key-value pairs.

Comment: have raised the ticket Log4j 2LOG4J2-695 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-695

Comment: Thanks a lot Remko and Ralph for answering all questions and providing the solution for Custom Logger over log4j2 with Splunk CIM. The Jira ticket has all details : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-695